# Using DESCryptoServiceProvider in Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app

Tags: uwp, des

I have an UWP app that communicate with my web service, and for using some methods my app must encrypt parameters.
For decryption we have used `DESCryptoServiceProvider and CryptoStream` in

```
System.Security.Cryptography
```

but UWP does not have the `System.Security.Cryptography,` and `Windows.Security.Cryptography` does not contain `DESCryptoServiceProvider and CryptoStream`!!!

Please help me Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Universal Windows apps, you have to use the [`CryptographicEngine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.cryptographicengine.aspx) for encrypt and decrypt operations.

For your decryption use-case, you'd use the [`DecryptAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.cryptographicengine.decryptasync.aspx) method, which requires - beside the encrypted data and the IV - a key to perform the operation.

The key you require will be created by the [`SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetrickeyalgorithmprovider.aspx) class. Therefore, initialize a new instance by opening the [desired algorithm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetricalgorithmnames.aspx) and create the key.

For example:

```cs
// Static method call, "SymmetricAlgorithmNames" has several DES algorithms,
// so choose the correct one
var provider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider
                   .OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.DesEcbPkcs7);
var key = provider.CreateSymmetricKey(myKeyMaterial);
```

Comment: do you know how to use an already existing key instead of creating a new one? The API doesn't seem to provide a way to "import" existing keys to use for symmetrical algorithms.

Comment: @disklosr It's the same method as above, just with a different `myKeyMaterial`. It's the same way as you'd use a password as key material. You'll end up with about 230 lines of code, using `IBuffer` and `CryptographicEngine.DeriveKeyMaterial` in between. It's not very intuitive, yeah.